# Reconciling the singular and plural in a title

Tags: grammatical-number

Here is the tile of a journal article: https://annals.org/aim/article-abstract/2724039/recognizing-potential-overdiagnosis-high-sensitivity-cardiac-troponin-assays-example

"Recognizing the Potential for Overdiagnosis: Are High-Sensitivity Cardiac Troponin Assays an Example?"

Hmm. I think it should be:

"Recognizing the Potential for Overdiagnosis: Is a High-Sensitivity Cardiac Troponin Assay an Example?"

The issue, of course, concerns the implications of a  high-sensitivity assay.

Thanks.

Howard

Comment: If you get rid of that "High-Sensitivity Cardiac Troponin" mumbo-jumbo and ask both: Are assays valuable? Is an assay valuable? I think you'll see they're both right. I don't know what the paper title intends. The matter is about whether the title is supposed to mean one assay or multiple assays.

Comment: In English, the subject and the complement of the verb *is* don't need to have the same plurality.

Comment: @PeterShor You mean to say "Is your cars large?" is OK?

Comment: No, I mean to say *his cars are his passion* is OK. The verb has to agree with the subject, but they don't need to agree with the complement.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh I see, you're saying in their example both "Are assays an example?" and "Are assays examples?" are both right.

Comment: Thanks! Both formulations are correct. An alternative could be:  “ Do High-Sensitivity Cardiac Troponin Assays result in the overdiagnosis of…?”  (Several assays are available to measure the level of troponins.)

Answer (score 0):

Your version and the given title are both correct.  Not knowing this medical term, I can only say that the person who is writing the paper is emphasizing the repeated occurrence cardiac assays.